# What is JID (job ID) and is it always smaller than PID?

Tags: process, jobs

I don't know what exactly is JID (job ID) and how it is assigned. What is it's relation to PID and how does one number affect the size of the other in any way?

Comment: What's the context? Are you talking about shell jobs?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a PID-JID combination?

Comment: Yes, I meant shell job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no relations between a PID and a job ID on shells I have used (`bash`, `dash` and `zsh`).

However, a shell job is a child process of the shell, whereas PID 1 (`init`) is the ancestor of all processes, including the shell. Therefore a process with job id 1 will *always* have a PID greater than the job ID.

The assignment of a job ID depends on the shell. On `bash`, usually the job ID assigned is one greater than the greatest job ID of a running background job:

```
$ sleep 1 & sleep 10 & sleep 1 &
[1] 11367
[2] 11370
[3] 11373
$ 
[1]   Done                    sleep 1
[3]+  Done                    sleep 1
$ sleep 1 &
[3] 11378
```